# yii2 export menu do not downloading file on remote server

Tags: export, yii2

I using extention export menu from kartik. And it's work fine. 
But only on my local OpenServer. When I pushing it on remote web server it is dont working.

I click to export button - choose exel 2007 format - opening blank windows where I have msg "file will be genereted" - click proccess - "generation..." - and here I receive msg "That web page is not available err_invalid_responde".

I do not know how debug this?

Comment: Maybe you have to look if the extension are trying to use some folder without write permissions

Answer (score 0):

You should enable debug module : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tool-debugger.html

But I think it is simply a dependency problem, you need [`xml`](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) and [`xmlwriter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/book.xmlwriter.php) php extensions to be able to use excel export, you should check `phpinfo()` for these extensions.